# Convert json into tree structure using javascript, client side

Tags: javascript, json

I want to convert the following json code which I have collected using get requests into a tree like structure

```
"rules": [{
  "name": "Rule1",
  "isFirst": true,

  "conditions": [{
    "outcomeTrue": {
      "GoToRule": "Rule2"
    },
    "outcomeFalse": {
      "ChangeStatus": {
        "GoToRule": "26"
      }
    },
    "outcomeError": {
      "ChangeStatus": {
        "GoToRule": "27"
      }
    },
  }],
},{
  "name": "Rule2",
  "isFirst": false,
  "conditions": [{
    "name": "history check idNumber",
    "outcomeTrue": {
        "GoToRule": "27"
    },
    "outcomeFalse": {
      "GoToRule": "Rule3"
    },
    "outcomeError": {
      "GoToRule": "26"
    },

  }],
}]
```

into something like this. Just a normal graph like this:

[image: A tree like graph structure]

Comment: Ok. Nice. Great. What did you try?

Comment: I am new to javascript. I just want to know libraries in javascript which can help me accomplish my task. I have written this code in java to convert it but then I found out that I can only work on client side  (any code which could be run on browser). Now I have to do it on client side and I cannot even get started. i just want a small push.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [D3.js' Tree](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083)

[Live Example](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/tree.html)

EDIT: Another example: [D3.js tree diagram generated from 'flat' data](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/8329404) (uses array of objects)

Comment: Oh okay, so you think i should parse my json using jquery, convert it into objects and then using d3.js library make a tree structure?

Comment: No. Just feed the JSON. Check out the examples thoroughly. :)